# Bus Error in C for Loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, bus-error

I have a toy cipher program which is encountering a bus error when given a very long key (I'm using 961168601842738797 to reproduce it), which perplexes me. When I commented out sections to isolate the error, I found it was being caused by this innocent-looking for loop in my Sieve of Eratosthenes.

```
unsigned long i;
int candidatePrimes[CANDIDATE_PRIMES];
// CANDIDATE_PRIMES is a macro which sets the length of the array to
// two less than the upper bound of the sieve. (2 being the first prime
// and the lower bound.)

for (i=0;i<CANDIDATE_PRIMES;i++)
{

  printf("i: %d\n", i); // does not print; bus error occurs first

  //candidatePrimes[i] = PRIME;

}
```

At times this has been a segmentation fault rather than a bus error.

Can anyone help me to understand what is happening and how I can fix it/avoid it in the future?

Thanks in advance!

PS

The full code is available here:

http://pastebin.com/GNEsg8eb

Comment: What is `CANDIDATE_PRIMES`? Most people won't go off site to look at your code.

Comment: Its just the length of the array, my mistake.

Comment: yeah, what is it's value? 2, 20, 200, 2436492364934623905473843674383 ?

Comment: Not the cause of your error, but's not very good coding practice to "hide" a variable in a macro definition. It would be better to use something like `#define CANDIDATE_PRIMES(x)  ((x) - FIRST_PRIME)` as you have done with your other macros.

Comment: @John3136: Very large. Evidently, too large. I'm editing it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're blowing the stack away.

```
unsigned long i;
int candidatePrimes[CANDIDATE_PRIMES];
```

If CANDIDATE_PRIMES is large, this alters the stack pointer by a massive amount. But it doesn't touch the memory, it *just* adjusts the stack pointer by a very large amount.

```
for (i=0;i<CANDIDATE_PRIMES;i++)
{
```

This adjusts "i" which is way back in the good area of the stack, and sets it to zero. Checks that it's < CANDIDATE_PRIMES, which it is, and so performs the first iteration.

```
printf("i: %d\n", i); // does not print; bus error occurs first
```

This attempts to put the parameters for "printf" onto the bottom of the stack. BOOM. Invalid memory location.

What value does CANDIDATE_PRIMES have?

And, do you *actually* want to store all the primes you're testing or only those that pass? What is the purpose of storing the values 0 thru CANDIDATE_PRIMES sequentially in an array???

If what you just wanted to store the primes, you should use a dynamic allocation and grow it as needed.

```
size_t g_numSlots = 0;
size_t g_numPrimes = 0;
unsigned long* g_primes = NULL;

void addPrime(unsigned long prime) {
    unsigned long* newPrimes;
    if (g_numPrimes >= g_numSlots) {
        g_numSlots += 256;
        newPrimes = realloc(g_primes, g_numSlots * sizeof(unsigned long));
        if (newPrimes == NULL) {
            die(gracefully);
        }
        g_primes = newPrimes;
    }
    g_primes[g_numPrimes++] = prime;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say your VLA is too large for your stack, leading to undefined behaviour.

Better to allocate the array dynamically:

```
int *candidatePrimes = malloc(CANDIDATE_PRIMES * sizeof(int));
```

And don't forget to `free` before returning.

If this is Eratosthenes Sieve, then the array is really just flags.  It's wasteful to use `int` if it's just going to hold 0 or 1.  At least use `char` (for speed), or condense to a bit array (for minimal storage).

Comment: I was implementing it with flags, but I was getting bogged down in making that work. Premature optimization being the root of all evil, I decided to be wasteful and come back to it later.

Comment: I just had a look at your code on pastebin.  You should define that `CANDIDATE_PRIMES` macro in parentheses so that multiplication works.  *ie* `#define CANDIDATE_PRIMES (n - FIRST_PRIME)`.  Without that, you'll have problems with the code I provided.  As an aside, please get out of the habit of excessively double-spacing your code.

Comment: The double spacing is mostly because I've been adding and deleting printf()'s, but I'll keep it in mind.